# Need a formula to count numbers beginning with specific digits in a string separated by commas

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula to count numbers beginning with specific digits in a string separated by commas

The 1st digit is always 1,2 or 3; second digit can be between 1 to 6. I need to count the numbers in the string beginning with 1, 2 and 3; and if those counts are greater than zero then count for their combinations with the second digit.

Here is the example with the expected solution. Lets say A1 has the following string:

```
11234,12345, 23456, 31423, 13009, 14001,24005, 12222, 21222, 33215, 21236
```

Then:

- B1 should return 5 (a count of all numbers in the string beginning with 1)
- C1 should be 3 (a count of all numbers in the string beginning with 2)
- D1 should be 2 (a count of all numbers in the string beginning with 3)

Comment: What have you tried already (I assume something with some combination of `countifs()` and `left()`?)

Comment: This would be easier to understand if your example included the solution (sample numbers, the result you would like to see from those numbers, and the logic for how you reached that result).  This question is pretty ambiguous.

Comment: Here is the example with a solution

Comment: @Adam: What I have tried so far is using Text to Column to split the string using the comma separator and the doing a count. That seems very cumbersome and manual. There has got to be a better way.

Comment: @fixer1234 : My previous comment seems to have got truncated. Here is the example with the expected solution. Lets say A1 has the following string: 11234,12345, 23456, 31423, 13009, 14001,24005, 12222, 21222, 33215, 21236; then, B1 should return 5 (a count of all numbers in the string beginning with 1); C1 should be 3 (a count of all numbers in the string beginning with 2); D1 should be 2 (a count of all numbers in the string beginning with 3)

Comment: Your example doesn't explain the 2nd digit combinations.  Also, are the spaces just for readability (cell contents are just digits and commas)?  Are the number groups always 5 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

`=(LEN(","&SUBSTITUTE($A$1,", ",","))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(","&SUBSTITUTE($A$1,", ",","), ","&B2,"")))/LEN(","&B2)`

(Where row *B* contains the strings you are trying to match within A1.)

---

How it works:

- You may notice that this appears twice: 
  `","&SUBSTITUTE($A$1,", ",",")`
  This takes out the spaces and adds a comma at the front, so your

*original string:* `11234,12345, 23456, 31423, 13009, 14001,24005, 12222, 21222, 33215, 21236`

becomes

*newString:* `,11234,12345,23456,31423,13009,14001,24005,12222,21222, 33215,21236`

- Now the long formula could be rewritten as : `=(LEN(newString)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(newString, ","&B2,""))) /LEN(","&B2)`
- Assuming that the initial digits you are looking for are in *B1* (e.g. *B1*`=1` this further collapses like this:

`=(LEN(newString)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(newString, ",1" ))) /LEN(",1")`

- So we have: Get length of the whole new string (67), then subtract length with all occurrences of `,1` removed (57).  That gives you the number of characters occupied by `,1` (10).  Divide by the length of `,1` (2) to tell you how many times `,1` occurred. (5)

You can drag this formula across row A, and put varying "search" digits in row *B* and it will count them all up.

Caveat:  *This will only work if the numbers are comma separated and/or comma-space separated, as in your example.*

Comment: This is simply awesome!! Seems to work beautifully. Thanks a ton. You rock!!

Answer (score 0):

https://exceljet.net/formula/count-numbers-that-begin-with look at this website.
So the formula is: =SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(L1:X20,1)="*(put digit you want to find here)*"))